# Quarkus SmallRye Reactive Messaging: Configure polling frequency to prevent continuous throwing of TooManyMessagesWithoutAckException (SRMSG18231)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging, quarkus-reactive

I'm using the quarkus (2.13.3.Final) plugin `quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka` (small-rye version 3.21.0) to program a non-blocking input queue deployed on kubernete's cluster to; receive a record, query an external api, do some logic and then emit an output:

Input configured as follows

```
    @Blocking(ordered = false)
    @OnOverflow(value = OnOverflow.Strategy.UNBOUNDED_BUFFER)
    @Acknowledgment(Acknowledgment.Strategy.MANUAL)
    @Incoming("queue")
```

Emitter:

```
    @Inject
    @Channel("result")
    Emitter<ScanResultValue> resultChannel;
```

Each record/event takes about 8 seconds to complete and output to the emitter.

The issue I have is that after a minute of starting up, SRMSG18231 `waitingForAckForTooLong` is thrown and kubernete's creates a new pod. This happens frequently enough for the state of the kubernete's deployment to go into a crash loop back off.

It seems the app is very greedy in taking records off the configured incoming queue via the poll method, within the class `KafkaThrottledLatestProcessedCommit` the number of `receivedOffsets` just goes up and up. Even though I log the start and end time for each event to ensure they are under the default `throttled.unprocessed-record-max-age.ms` time of 60 seconds (they are never longer than 10 seconds), the throttled message processor will throw a SRMSG18231 because there are hundreds of events that have not been started yet. This triggers the kubernete's pod to be recreated via the small rye health endpoint becoming `KO`.

I've looked at the following configuration options to try and limit the number of messages taken from the queue each poll - and I've also tried to limit how often the poll method picks up new offsets for processing - but nothing really seems to make a difference:

```
mp.messaging.incoming.queue.max-inflight-messages=1
mp.messaging.incoming.queue.max-queue-size-factor=1
mp.messaging.incoming.queue.poll-timeout=30000
mp.messaging.incoming.queue.max.poll.records=20
```

For instance the above set of config I would expect to only take 20 events each poll - and not to take on more until those 20 are complete. Though from debugging the code it doesn't seem this is the purpose of `max.poll.records`. I also expected the elapsed time in deciding if we have `waitedTooLong` (`long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - peek.getReceivedAt();`) to take the start time in milliseconds of when that poll batch of 20 records began - however, it doesn't seem to do that and seems to take the start time from the first message it receives and never updates it (Even though my app acknowledges 200 events within the time the app is up).

My only solution to the issue as I can see is to set:

`mp.messaging.incoming.queue.throttled.unprocessed-record-max-age.ms=-1`

So that the throttled latest processed commit class cannot throw SRMSG18231. The kubernete's pod remains healthy, however, I'm very confused about how to limit the rate of message uptake - and I don't really want to keep the value at `-1`.

Any help appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to respect the [Chain of Acknowledgement](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.1/acknowledgement/acknowledgement.html#_chain_of_acknowledgment) :

```
return Message.of(in.getPayload() + 1,
    () -> {
        // Called when the consumer acknowledges the message
        // ...
        // Don't forget to acknowledge the incoming message:
        return in.ack();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have max.poll.records=20 and each message takes about 10 seconds, I think that the record number 20 takes 200 seconds since poll time to the ack. Try increasing throttled.unprocessed-record-max-age.ms up to 200 seconds or decrease max.poll.records to 4/5 to verify (4 * 10 seconds) < 60 seconds .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!